# Django: DetailView URL with PK Issue

Tags: python, regex, django, webapp2, keyword-argument

I'm new to Django and I am trying to build a church directory application to manage users (sheep) in churches (flocks). Everything seems to work until I add a CBV - DetailView for a model named ChurchMembers. I want to use the pk of the ChurchMember to create a DetailView for the member to have a profile.

I get the following error message in the Debug:

```
NoReverseMatch at /flock/members/
Reverse for 'view_member_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['flock/members/(?P<member_pk>\\d+)/$']
```

Here is my views.py (only displaying the DetailView in question):

```
class view_member_detail(DetailView):
model = models.ChurchMember
template_name = 'flock_app/member_profile.html'
context_object_name = 'member_detail'
pk_url_kwarg = 'member_pk'
```

I have a hunch that this is related to the way my urls.py file is setup. Maybe incorrect regex, or possibly bad ordering. urls.py below:

```
app_name = 'flock_app'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='user_logout'),
    url(r'^add_church/$', views.add_church, name='add_church'),
    url(r'^add_member/$', views.add_member, name='add_member'),
    url(r'^members/$', views.view_members_list.as_view(), name='view_members_list'),
    url(r'^members/(?P<member_pk>\d+)/$', views.view_member_detail.as_view(), name='view_member_detail'),
    url(r'^churches2/$', views.view_churches_list.as_view(), name='view_churches_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.view_churches_detail.as_view(), name='view_churches_detail'),
    url(r'^update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.update_church_detail.as_view(), name='update_church_detail'),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.delete_church.as_view(), name='delete_church'),
    url(r'^home', views.home, name='home')
]
```

Here is my call the DetailView from the HTML:

```
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'flock_app:view_member_detail' pk=mem.member_pk %}">Sheep Profile</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete sheep</a>
  <div/>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT - Source code for HTML Added**

```
{% extends 'flock_app/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{%  block body_block%}

<div class="jumbotron">
  {% if members %}

  <h1 class="display-3 text-center">All Sheep in Flocks <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="location.href='{% url 'flock_app:add_member' %}'">Add Sheep</button></h1>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class=>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col">Flock</th>
        <th scope="col">First Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <th scope="col">Phone</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for mem in members %}
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"></th>
        <td>{{ mem.Flock }}</td>
        <td>{{ mem.First_Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ mem.Last_Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ mem.Email }}</td>
        <td>{{ mem.Phone_Number }}</td>
        <td>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Manage</a></th>
          <div/>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'flock_app:view_member_detail' pk=mem.member_pk %}">Sheep Profile</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete sheep</a>
          <div/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      <table/>
  {% else %}

    <h1 class="text-center">No Sheep Found</h1>
    <h1 class="lead text-center">Click <a href="{% url 'flock_app:add_member' %}">here</a> to add Sheep to <em>His</em>_Flock</h2>

  {% endif %}


</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT 2 - DJANGO ERROR CODES**

```
NoReverseMatch at /flock/members/
Reverse for 'view_member_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['flock/members/(?P<member_pk>\\d+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/flock/members/
Django Version: 1.11.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'view_member_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['flock/members/(?P<member_pk>\\d+)/$']
Exception Location: C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 497
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe
Python Version: 3.5.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\gabrielcastillo\\Google Drive\\git_base\\flock',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\python35.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Wed, 18 Jul 2018 02:21:37 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\gabrielcastillo\Google Drive\git_base\flock\templates\flock_app\base.html, error at line 0

Reverse for 'view_member_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['flock/members/(?P<member_pk>\\d+)/$']
```

Answer (score 0):

urls change from

```
url(r'^members/(?P<member_pk>\d+)/$', views.view_member_detail.as_view(), name='view_member_detail'),
```

to

```
url(r'^members/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.view_member_detail.as_view(), name='view_member_detail'),
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Unfortunately, that didn't resolve it.  Same error.

Comment: I am using a call to pk for 2 different models. Could Django be mixing them up?

Comment: make sure your mem.member_pk is not '' by list it in template with {{mem.member_pk}}

Comment: I just tried this! Still did not resolve. I do not get an error page now though! I can click the link, but it does not take me anywhere, nor does the url change.

Comment: post the source code about `<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'flock_app:view_member_detail' pk=mem.member_pk %}">Sheep Profile</a>` in html

Comment: I mean the code in browser which is generated by django

Comment: Added to the post!

Comment: so you still not change member_pk to pk in urls.py?

Comment: Hi! it has been changed to <pk> in urls.py. No change, still same error!

Comment: make sure mem.member_pk is not ''

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue! Looks like I made a call to another View in the HTML page which was throwing an error. Once that cleared up, I was able to access all my pages with corresponding ok info!